# RESfulT API Design: Is following implementation as per the rest good practices or not?

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

We have a big list ("collection") with a number of entities ("items").The items are manually sortable via an **order property** on the item.
Now we wanted to expose this mechanism to users where they can update the complete sorting of all items in one call.
So , we thought of implementing it via following web services.

1. Retrives a particular item
   **GET /collections/123/items/{item_id}**
2. Get current order:
   **GET /collections/123/items/ordering**

   Suppose we have 3 items with respective id and order as following:

   100 -> 1

   101 -> 2

   102 -> 3

   so the query **GET /collections/123/items/ordering** will give Response : [100, 101, 102] -> 
   it returns the  list of ids in the current order.
3. Set new order: **PUT /collections/123/items/ordering**

   if we want to set new order of items as following:

   100 -> 2

   101 -> 3

   102 -> 1

   we can do that via   **PUT /collections/123/items/ordering**

   and passing [102, 100, 101] in body.

   Please note that while setting new order the users can give any order not just the increasing or decreasing order.
4. Return list of items 
   **GET "/collections/123/items"**

   Now we have following  query:
   In method 4 we are returning just the list of items and not the order.

   1. Is our implementation as per the rest API standards or not ?
   2. If not what are other possible ways to implement ordering in restful way??

Comment: what's the meaning of 123 in "/collections/123/items/{item_id}"? Is it the identifier number of a collection in the collections list?

Comment: I would rather add an orderIndex property to the items instead and use PATCH on the collection if it has to be changed. But your solution is okay either, so if it is easier for you that way, than do it that way!

Comment: @inf3rno : my main concern is that we are using 2 resources "item" and "ordering" in a single collection of "items"
But, When we do GET "/collections/123/items" we only retrieve the list of items and not the order.
i did google for any kind of similar example but could not find 1.
Is it as per the practices of rest API standards?

Comment: @b.singh I sent an answer, it would have been too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way.

1) - Get Item  - **`GET /v1/items/{item_id}`**

2) - Get Items with default Order  - **`GET /v1/items/`**

3) - Get Items with Asc Order  - **`GET /v1/items?orderby=asc`**

**EDIT With More Explanation Behind RESTFUL API**

- Rest ful API designed around the notion that API end point represents the resource and use HTTP verbs (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT) as actions on it.
   In your case ***items*** are resource. Use the above verbs to apply actions on this resource.

  From your question your requirement is not very clear, but I am assuming you want

**Either** you want to retrieve items in a specific order, in which case use pass the order by parameter as a query string

> ```
> **`GET /v1/items?orderby=asc`**
> ```

**Or**  you want update the order of the items that are stored in database. (BTW I did not see this kind of requirement before, usual practice is to retrieve the list in the order you want. If you want to preserve the previous order set, then store an option to save the default order and enable API to change it. )

> ```
> **`PUT /v1/items/order`**
> ```
>
> Send the json object as body `{ "sortby":"xxx",order:"asc" }` or `[2,3,1]`

Comment: Answers like this are not useful unless you explain why you would do it this way

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Updated the answer as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems a little bit strange, at least I have never seen something like this...

An alternative would be to pass the "order by" as query parameter, like `GET /collections/123/items?orderby=lastModifiedDate`

An second alternative would be to a look at [OData](http://www.odata.org/), it provides query syntax and also includes "orderby".

Edit

I missed the "not just asc/desc" part, so having an orderby query parameter is not enough.

Comment: @b.singh Ok, I see I missed that. In this case, having an orderby query-parameter is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of them are correct:

**GET "/collections/{collectionId}/items"** => Retrieve all items in collection {collectionId}

**GET "/collections/{collectionId}/items/{itemId}"** => Retrieve item {itemId} in collection {collectionId}

**PUT "/collections/{collectionId}/items/ordering"** => Update items ordering in collection {collectionId}

In my opinion the following one is not correct:

**GET "/collections/{collectionId}/items/ordering"**

That's because I read this as "retrieve items ordering in collection {collectionId}". Instead, I'd do something like:

**GET "/collections/{collectionId}/items?sortBy=ordering** => Retrieve all items in collection {collectionId} and sorting them by ordering method

Comment: my main concern is that we are using 2 resources "item" and "ordering" in a single collection of "items"
But, When we do GET "/collections/123/items" we only retrieve the list of items and not the order.
i did google for any kind of similar example but could not find 1.
Is it as per the practices of rest API standards?

Answer (score 0):

> my main concern is that we are using 2 resources "item" and "ordering"
>   in a single collection of "items" But, When we do GET
>   "/collections/123/items" we only retrieve the list of items and not
>   the order. i did google for any kind of similar example but could not
>   find 1. Is it as per the practices of rest API standards?

There is no standard about how to sort a list manually, this is an implementation detail, so this depends on your taste.

I think your solution is okay, since there is no constraint about how to build URLs either, so don't worry about that, you could use `GET /fwslgbssbh/` too as long as there is link metadata attached from which the client can understand what this link does (self-descriptive message, HATEOAS).

I would prefer these links:

- `GET /list/` - to get list items in random order
- `GET /list/?sortBy="index:ascending"` - to sort list items manually (by index)
- `GET /list/123` - to get an item
- `PUT /list/?fields="id,index" [{id:123, index: 1}, {id: 456, index: 2}, ...]` - to update order index of every item, the fields part is not necessary in the URL, it is just to distinguish the link from other PUT links to the same resource, so this way it will be easier to route
- `PATCH /list/?fields="id,index" {move: [{id: 456, index: 5}]}` - to change the order index of a single item, e.g. move item 456 to the 5th position on the list

If you have multiple manual orders, e.g. a single order per user then ofc. you need a different structure.